# Azure AD B2C Custom policy social buttons order

Tags: html, azure, authentication, single-sign-on, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I just wondering is there any way to manipulate the order of the social login buttons at custom policies?
So in the example below, not FB bus MS login button is the first:

[image]

rgds,

'Child

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My college just figured out the answer:

```
UserJourney Id="policyName">
        <OrchestrationSteps>
            <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
                <ClaimsProviderSelections>
                    <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange"/>
                    <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="SigninwithGoogle"/>
                    <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="SigninwithFacebook"/>
                    <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="SigninwithApple"/>
                </ClaimsProviderSelections>
                <ClaimsExchanges>
                    <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email"/>
                </ClaimsExchanges>
            </OrchestrationStep>
</OrchestrationSteps>
```

So if I change the  element's order then the button order will change on the login page.

Comment: will it work with "Send verification code", "Continue", "Change" and other general buttons?

Comment: @AkmalSalikhov I have no idea. The result above is referring to an OrchestrationStep but the elements you are mentioning are referred in a different part of the description file.